# HTML/JS How to position a rectangle relative to 'any' side of the parent canvas element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

In `HTML/CSS` we can align a child to any side of the parent through: `top`, `right`, `left`, `bottom`

Can this be applied to rectangles, lines etc.. on `canvas`'s? 
Alternatively is their a way to use percentages in positioning?

My end goal is to get a rectangle whose position snaps to the right of the canvas and stays their if the canvas is resized.

I can't seam to figure out a way to do this.

This is what I'm working with it.

```
ctx.rect(20,20,150,100);
```

Comment: If possible , can post `html` , `js` , create stacksnippets / jsfiddle ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html & CSS can reposition child elements because the definitions of those children are saved in the Document **Object** Model (DOM).

The Html Canvas element does not save the definitions of any rectangles, lines, etc. that it draws on itself.  Therefore, it cannot "recall" your rectangle to reposition it.  To Canvas, your rectangle becomes unremembered pixels on its bitmap display.

To reposition your rectangle, you will have to manually "remember" its definition using code.  This is usually done by saving your rectangle's definition in a javascript object like this:

```
var myRect={
    x:20,
    y:20,
    width:150,
    height:100,
}
```

When you want to reposition a canvas rectangle (as when you want it to "stick" to a resized canvas), you:

1. Resize the canvas. (Note: resizing the canvas element automatically clears its contents).
2. Calculate the new [x,y] that will keep your rectangle "stuck" to the right side of the canvas. If you want your rectangle stuck to the right side, you recalculate: `var newX=canvas.width-myRect.width`
3. Change the [x,y] in `myRect` to those new x,y values.
4. Use myRect to redraw your rectangle in its new desired postion.

Here's annotated example code and a Demo:

```js
// canvas related variables
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// the definition of your rectangle 
// (this definition is used when your rectangle must be redrawn)
var myRect={
  x:20,
  y:20,
  width:150,
  height:100,
}

// call helper function to reset your rectangle's "x"
// so it's positioned to the right side
stickRight(myRect);

// call helper function to redraw your rectangle
redrawRect(myRect);

// listen for changes in the html slider that resizes the canvas
$myslider=$('#myslider');
$myslider.change(function(){

  // fetch the scaling factor the user has specified with the slider
  var scale=parseInt($(this).val());

  // resize the canvas to the specified size
  // NOTE: resizing the canvas automatically erases all content
  canvas.width=cw*scale/100;
  canvas.height=ch*scale/100;

  // again call helper function to reset your rectangle's "x"
  // so it's positioned to the right side
  stickRight(myRect);

  // call helper function to redraw your rectangle
  redrawRect(myRect);
});


function stickRight(rect){
  rect.x=canvas.width-myRect.width;
}

function redrawRect(rect){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height);
  ctx.stroke()
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Resize: <input id=myslider type=range min=0 max=200 value=100><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```